# Within a Cell TEXT then A1 then TEXT

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I wrote a function that allows me to pull data from Cell E2 and insert it after text.
Cell E2  has number 555.
In cell E3 I have added function **="Total: "&E2**  giving me output **Total: 555**.

I want to be able to add text behind the 555 within the cell so that it says: **Total: 555 pictures**

I cannot figure out how to get text behind the 555 within my **="Total: "&E2** function

Thanks ahead of time, Ed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the string you want after it, the same way you added E2:

`="Total: "&E2&" pictures"`

Alternatively, you could use the `CONCATENATE` function:

`=CONCATENATE("Total: ",E2," pictures")`